# Wijmo FlexGrid column width as header text Angluar2

Tags: angular, wijmo, c1flexgrid

I want the full header text of the Wijmo FlexGrid header visible:

[image: See Image].

How can I do it with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue while doing the same here is how i solved this:

css changes:

```
.wjcGrid .wj-colheaders   .wj-header {
    text-overflow: initial;
}
```

html changes:

```
 <wj-flex-grid  #flex 
    [itemsSource]="data" 
    [isReadOnly]="true" 
    [headersVisibility]="'Column'" 
    [selectionMode]="'Row'" 
    (loadedRows)="onGridLoaded($event)" 
    [autoSizeMode] = "'Headers'">
 </wj-flex-grid>
```

In component:

```
  onGridLoaded(){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
             self.flex.autoSizeColumns();
        },300);
  }
```

> you can remove `setTimeout` from the above method,as i have used because i had some rendering issue when i was loading same grid multiple times.

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah, this works for me. In my version on wijmo, it was not supporting (loadedRows) so used auto size after assigning value

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-overflow property and set it to ellipsis

[Refer w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow)

Comment: i don't want (...), I want that whole text visible

Comment: Give   width: auto!important;

Answer (score 0):

You should use AutoSize property of Flexgrid. Check this thread:
http://wijmo.com/topic/auto-adjust-height-for-flexgrid-column-headers/

Answer (score 0):

I am working on HTML5/Angular JS 4 application using TypeScript. I need to wrap my column header. I simply did like below and it worked.

```
<wj-flex-grid #studentsWjFlexGrid [itemsSource]="studentsPerformanceData" style=" height:100%; width:100%">
    <wj-flex-grid-column binding="longDescription" [width]="100" [wordWrap]="true">
        <ng-template wjFlexGridCellTemplate cellType="ColumnHeader">
            <span style="word-wrap: break-word;">Long Description Goes here</span>
        </ng-template>
    </wj-flex-grid-column>
</wj-flex-grid>
```